# Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to render a Json Response on a html site using AJAX but i keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous
```

> 

JsonResponse in Question:

```
["[53.50119612705815, -1.1270833894501477] -> [53.34474, -3.01101]", "[53.50119612705815, -1.1270833894501477] -> [53.34474, -3.01101]", "[52.04061648544843, -0.6655072691644374] -> [51.90829, -0.5127]", "[52.04061648544843, -0.6655072691644374] -> [51.90829, -0.5127]", "[52.04061648544843, -0.6655072691644374] -> [51.90829, -0.5127]", "[53.50119612705815, -1.1270833894501477] -> [53.42705, -0.94339]"]
```

> 

Html file with AJAX and JS:

```
<div class="'row">
    <div id="test">  
        <h1> Test </h1>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/network/dispatch_data/',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                 $('#test').append(response.data);
           }
        });
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When i inspect element in my browser, the error points to the  `data: data` being the source of the error. Any idea what i'm doing wrong? I can view the url perfectly with the json response but making it show with ajax is proving a problem

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you don't understand, but as the error pointed out, your `data` variable is not defined. The error occur before your ajax execution, so its not coming from the response, but during the request.

Comment: I dont know what i dont know but damn it your answer worked!!! woop woop

Comment: yep, i just added ```var data = '';``` inside my function and boom it loaded in the console!

Comment: or you could remove `data: data,` I guess...basically you are creating a POST request to the server and not sending any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `data` as the body of your request, but first you have to defined the object you are sending to API

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="test">
    <h1> Test </h1>
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}

<script>
  const data = {
    bar: [1, 2, 3],
    foo: false
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/network/dispatch_data/',
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#test').append(response.data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```